# Ajax.Request как вернуть значение

Tags: javascript

Доброе время суток! Подскажите как вернуть значение из Ajax.Request в dataSource

```
new Ajax.Request(
            'index.php',
            {queue: {position: 'end', scope: 'command'},
             method: 'post',
             postBody: 'module=Reports&action=ReportsAjax&mode=ajax&file=ReportAutoHome&report=gr',
             onComplete: function(response) {
                iteam = [{ date: '01-06-2013 Sat', dayT: 65942, nightT: 13860 },{ date: '03-06-2013 Mon', dayT: 169709, nightT: 35611 }];
                onCompleteFunction(iteam);

            }
        }
    );
function onCompleteFunction(data) {
 var dataSource = iteam;
return dataSource;
 }
 alert(onCompleteFunction('iteam'));
var dataSource = onCompleteFunction();
```

такой вариант не работает, а вот если то норм.

```
function onCompleteFunction(data) {
 var dataSource = [{ date: '01-06-2013 Sat', dayT: 65942, nightT: 13860 },{ date: '03-06-2013 Mon', dayT: 169709, nightT: 35611 }];
return dataSource;
 }
 alert(onCompleteFunction('iteam'));
var dataSource = onCompleteFunction();
```

Answer (score 2):

Немного теории:

`JavaScript` - это асинхронный язык, поэтому во время запроса на сайт, скрипт не блокируется, а продолжает выполнять свой сценарий.

Т.е. как работает скрипт:

Делается запрос на сайт, выводится сообщение `alert()`, присваивается переменная, а уже после того, как запрос на сайт был выполнен, переменной `src` присваивается значение.

По сути вам нужно присваивать переменной dataSource значение только после того, как сработает событие `onComplete` метода `Ajax.Request()`.

```
function somefunction(){
    new Ajax.Request('index.php', {
        queue: {position: 'end', scope: 'command'},
        method: 'post',
        postBody: 'module=Reports&action=ReportsAjax&mode=ajax&file=ReportAutoHome&report=gr',
        onComplete: function(response) {
            src = response.responseText;

            onCompleteFunction(src);
        }
    });
};

function onCompleteFunction(data) {
    alert(data);
    var dataSource = src;
}
```

Comment: Отлично работает! спс! А возможно что бы dataSource не был в функции ?

Comment: @machanics это просто как пример. Переменная dataSource может быть в обработчике события onComplete, т.е.:

    onComplete: function(response) {
        var dataSource = response.responseText;
    }

Comment: все ровно что то не так, я там изменил немного не глянешь сверху.

Comment: @machanics напиши словами, как ты видишь работу алгоритма. В этом кроется проблема.

Comment: Ajax.Request берет из php ({ date: '01-06-2013 Sat', dayT: 65942, nightT: 13860 }) и возвращает в dataSource а из него уже берет вот этот скрипт http://chartjs.devexpress.com/Demos/VizGallery/#chart/chartslineandpointseriesspline как то так

Comment: @machanics нет, давайте каждый шаг: аякс делает запрос на сервер, объявляется функция onCompleteFunction(), срабатывает alert(), переменной dataSource присваивается undefined, т.к. функция onCompleteFunction() ничего не возвращает. По завершению запроса к сайту в переменную iteam заносится массив и этот массив передается в вызываемую функцию onCompleteFunction().

Comment: Наверно как то так или я чего то не догоняю.